# javafx CheckBoxTreeItem<File> TreeView<File>. How to show only the name of file and not the full path?

Tags: file, javafx, path, treeview

Thanks in advance for support...
I'm coding in JavaFx using TreeView class and CheckBoxTreeItem. I want to show in the treeview the CheckBoxTreeItem (File) only the name of Path or File, and all sub, that user choice. All the stuff about selecting path, flush trow work fine, but when I upload this on the treeview the object show the full path of file and not the name. I want only show the name.

[image]
To do this I use a class that extend CheckBoxTreeItem:

```
public class FilePathTreeItem_analisi extends CheckBoxTreeItem<File>
```

My question is this: When I add this to the TreeView in this way:

```
TreeView<File> treview_Base;
treview_Base.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.<File>forTreeView());
FilePathTreeItem_analisi Ckaggiunto = new FilePathTreeItem_analisi(file.toPath());
```

.. and other command that correct upload file

Why its show the full path and not only the name?

This is the class of CheckBoxTreeItem:

```
public class FilePathTreeItem_analisi extends CheckBoxTreeItem<File>
public FilePathTreeItem_analisi(Path file){
super(file.toFile());
dilavoro =file;

this.fullPath=file.toString();
this.setIndependent(false);

//test if this is a directory and set the icon
if(Files.isDirectory(file)){
  this.isDirectory=true;
  this.setGraphic(new ImageView(folderCollapseImage));
}else{
  this.isDirectory=false;
  this.setGraphic(new ImageView(fileImage));
}

this.setValue(file.toFile());
```

... and some listyener and eventHandler...

So my question is: what I have to use in the class that extend  CheckBoxTreeItem to show in the TreeView the name of the file and not the entire path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
StringConverter<File> converter = new StringConverter<File>() {

    @Override
    public String toString(File file) {
        return file.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public File fromString(String string) {
        // not used by CheckBoxTreeCell:
        return null ;
    }
};

treview_Base.setCellFactory(tv -> {
    CheckBoxTreeCell<File> cell = new CheckBoxTreeCell<>();
    cell.setConverter(converter);
    return cell ;
});
```

instead of

```
treview_Base.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.<File>forTreeView());
```